# Magento2: Mixin is undefined on deploying static content

Tags: magento2, less, static-content, mixins

I have created several mixins in my custom theme within the file "_mixins.less", these work locally and are loaded properly from my other less files. However, when I want to deploy static content I get the following compilation error:

```
Compilation from source: /var/projects/**project**/magento2/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less

Compilation from source: 
frontend/GetNoticed/**project**/en_US/css/email-fonts.less
.anim-fade is undefined in /var/projects/**project**/magento2/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/GetNoticed/**project**/en_US/css/source/_theme.less
```

This only happens when it tries to compile less files from parent themes ( Luma or Blank ). I also get the same error in my Firebug console on the product page, within the gallery.css file.

The function .anim-fade doesn't do more than adding a simple transition effect:

```
.anim-fade(@element; @duration) {
  transition: @element ease-in-out @duration;
  -webkit-transition: @element ease-in-out @duration;
  -moz-transition: @element ease-in-out @duration;
  -o-transition: @element ease-in-out @duration;
}
```

Which works fine on all elements that use this. My _sources.less file looks like this:

```
@import '_mixins.less';
@import '_variables.less';
@import (reference) '_extends.less';
@import '_theme';
@import '_typography.less';
@import '_layout.less';
@import '_tables.less';
@import '_messages.less';
@import '_navigation.less';
@import '_tooltips.less';
@import '_loaders.less';
@import '_forms.less';
@import '_icons.less';
@import '_buttons.less';
@import '_sections.less';
@import '_pages.less'; // Theme pager
@import '_actions-toolbar.less';
@import '_breadcrumbs.less';
@import '_popups.less';
@import '_price.less';
@import '_bootstrap.less';
@import '_fonts.less'; /* theme fonts */
@import '_header.less'; /* theme heading */
@import '_homepage.less'; /* page specific styling */
@import '_checkout.less'; /* custom checkout styling */
@import '_productgrid.less'; /* products-grid search results */
@import '_product.less'; /* products-grid search results */
@import '_sidebar.less'; /* sidebars pages */
```

I'm absolutely clueless why it's doing this, all my other mixins are compiling just fine. I've tried renaming the mixin from "fade-transition" to "lib-fade-transition" to "anim-fade", but this didn't help.

Hoping to find answers here, thanks in advance!